# Finding a numerical solution to a equation expressed as a sum in Python

Tags: python, scipy, numeric, sympy

I want to find a numerical solution to a equation expressed as a infinite sum in Python. An simplified example using `fsolve()` and `sympy` would be:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
from sympy import *

i = symbols('i', integer=True)

def f(x):
        return Sum(x**i, (i,0, oo)).evalf(10)-1

print fsolve(f, 0.5)
```

I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_commutative'
```

I tried substituting the infinite sum with a sum with only a finite number of terms, and also casting the function f() output type to float, but I got the same error. Though this seems like an easy task I could not find a solution to this problem on StackOverflow or in the documentation.

My question is: how do I numerically solve equations that are expressed using a sum in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular sum is nothing but a sum of a geometric series. `sympy` concurs:

```
In [23]: x = symbols('x')

In [24]: i = symbols('i', integer=True)

In [25]: Sum(x**i, (i, 0, oo)).doit()
Out[25]: Piecewise((1/(-x + 1), Abs(x) < 1), (Sum(x**i, (i, 0, oo)), True))
```

Notice that it diverges for `x >=1`. Sympy raises an error (try `f(1.1)`), which the guts of `fsolve` are not prepated to handle, and this somehow leads to the error you see.

In general, I don't think there's anything special about solving equations with l.h.s. being evaluated as a sum. You need to make sure this way or another that the function you present to `fsolve` or its relatives actually returns a numerical output.

Moreover, `fsolve` (i) expects that your function is reasonably smooth *and* (ii) it does not handle bounds. This way, if you need to limit the range for the root-finding, you are better off using, say `brentq`.
(In higher dimensions, look for `least_squares`.)

In principle, you could use try-except in your function and return `nan` in case of no convergence. This is likely to only baffle the solver, and the return value can very well be garbage.

Comment: Interesting, Brentq does not rise the error, however the error still persists for fsolve in case of sums that are convergent for all real numbers. This solved my problem.